# XML preserving leading whitespace, but not trailing whitespaces

Tags: java, xml, whitespace

Let's say I have this:

```
<value> Some value</value>
```

Trying to read the value with:

```
value=someParent.getElementsByTagName("value").item(0).getTextContent().trim();
```

gives me `"Some value"`
, but the actual text would be `" Some value"`.

I know `trim()` leaves out leading and trailing white spaces, but is there an existing method (besides actually adding some lines of code to treat this specific case in particular) in order to have only the trailing white spaces eliminated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression can help you :

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

the `replaceAll()` can actually take the place of `trim()` in your example :

```
value=someParent.getElementsByTagName("value").item(0).getTextContent().replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
```

but I would definitly try to make that more readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the methods from the Apache commons StringUtils: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html

They have `strip`-methods where you can look at the sourcecode and e.g. adapt the stripEnd method to your needs.